# "the 10-years evolution show..." or "the 10-year evolution shows..."

Tags: numbers, dates, dashes

What is the correct sentence between these two forms:

> "the 10-years evolution show..."

or

> "the 10-year evolution shows...".

?

Both answers seem okay to me. Also, what about the dash between 10 and year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct is ***"the 10-year evolution shows"***. The 10-year is adjective for evolution, it clarifies the period of evolution.